# Color overlap in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<table border="1" class="sample">

<tr>
<th>Employee</th>
<th>Salary</th> 
<th></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>EMP1</td>
<td>10000</td>
<td><input id="btn1" type="button" value="Submit">
</tr>

<tr>
<td>EMP2</td>
<td>12000</td>
<td><input id="btn2" type="button" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've set the alternating color in the css. That is first row is white and second row is yellow.
The problem is the button in the second row is also getting yellow color. I've set Opacity to 0.5 so that it looks greyed out on pageload. How to remove this color overlap?

```
<style type="text/css">
table.sample {
    border: 6px inset #8B8378;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
}
table.sample td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.2em 2ex 0.2em 2ex;
    color: black;
}
table.sample tr.d0 td {
    background-color: #FCF6CF;
}
table.sample tr.d1 td {
    background-color: #FEFEF2;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your CSS and elaborate on why you've given your button 0.5 opacity in the first place?

Comment: "I've set the Opacity of that button to 0.5. How to remove this color overlap?" Easy ... remove the opacity! Opacity less than 1 makes an element partly see-through. What else would you expect to happen? Perhaps you should just select an appropriate color.

Comment: Thanks, Ralph! for your quick reply. But I want Opacity but still want to remove the color. Is that possible?

Comment: You can start by closing your html tags properly..

Comment: Opacity means what is lying underneath an element shines through. So if you want something else than the background color of the TR to shine through your button, then you have to place something else behind your button.

Comment: in your question its not clear what you want to achieve... you want it transparent but, you don't want to see the background through it... Then don't make it transparent.. Do you want the button to be gray? set it gray.. do you want it disabled set the input 'disabled' ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/SqY9P/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
input {color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

E.g. http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/gGIiw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

table {
    border: 6px inset #8B8378;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.2em 2ex 0.2em 2ex;
    color: black;
}
table tr td {
    background-color: #FCF6CF;
}
table tr td {
    background-color: #FEFEF2;
}

input {color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<table border="1" class="simple">

<tr>
<th>Employee</th>
<th>Salary</th> 
<th></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>EMP1</td>
<td>10000</td>
<td><input id="btn1" type="button" value="Submit">
</tr>

<tr>
<td>EMP2</td>
<td>12000</td>
<td><input id="btn2" type="button" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You won't get see through with what I posted. Change the bg color to black as a test. Make sure to remove the opacity.

Answer (score 2):

[`opacity`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity) makes your element see-through. An opacity of `0.5` will make the element appear 50% see-through.

The reason you can see your background colour through your `input` is because your input has this opacity. You're basically asking "I have added a window to my house but I can see through it, how can I prevent this?", and the answer is simply: remove the opacity.

Here is a JSFiddle demo showing 0.0 opacity, 0.5 opacity and no opacity in action: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/UQ48z/1.

[image: Example]

If you want your button to have a different coloured background whilst retaining its opacity, what you can do is wrap it in a `span` and then give that span a background:

```
<td>
    <span>
        <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Submit">
    </span>
</td>
```

```
td span { background:#fff; } /* New button background colour */
td span input { margin:0; }  /* Remove the button's margins */
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/UQ48z/2/).

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way to achieve this without using Opacity? I meant that I want the grayedout effect(like disabled) for the button  equivalent to 0.5 Opacity?

Comment: You can give that particular cell a white background, but this looks a bit strange. `table.sample tr td:nth-child(3) { background:#fff; }`.

Comment: @User I've added a new example using a `span`. This should fix your issue.